# How do I pass the form to the get_context_data function?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

How can I get the form variable here?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = kwargs['form']
    return context
```

Comment model code:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

text = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

View class:

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Comment
fields = ('text', )
template_name = 'post/details.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = kwargs['form']
    return context
```

DetailView:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
context_object_name = 'post'
template_name = 'post/details.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

Comment: The create view would add the form to the context itself. Why do you need to add it yourself?

Comment: You don't need to pass the form to the context yourself,  `CreateView` already adds the form to the context

Comment: A `CreateView` will *already* has a variable named form, so it *is* already in the context. There is no need to do this yourself.

Comment: Even with two different views accessing one template? my form doesnt show up with that code

Comment: @adrq Why do you need two views? If you want to display the details of one model and also have a form try inheriting from `django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin` you would have to override and adjust the `get` and `post` methods though.

Comment: Okay, I didnt know about it, thank you very much for help :), have a nice day guys